# Table td tr html label select (trying to parent/link drop down options inside two drop down tabs)

Tags: html, html-table, html-select, parent

I have got these two drop down tabs/options and I was hoping someone could help me fix my little problem. I am trying to select an option inside category and then only be able to select options related inside the subcategory instead of been able to select everything. Trying to parent the options related to each other to be displayed basically..

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Category</td>
    <td><label>
      <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
        <option value="Headwear">Headwear</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right">Subcategory</td>
    <td>
       <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option value="beanie">beanie</option>
         <option value="Cap">cap</option>
         <option value="Shirts">Shirt</option>
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is more of a JavaScript then html issue. Do you have a JavaScript framework your using? Also unless you have tabular data its a bad idea to use tables for layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery try this, [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qdqokg0p/6/)

```
$('#category').change(function(event){
    var subcategory = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('#subcategory');
    var selectedCat = $(this).val();
    if(selectedCat != false) {
        $(subcategory).prop('disabled', false).val(0);;
        $(subcategory).find("[data-target='" + selectedCat + "']").show()
        $(subcategory).find("[data-target!='" + selectedCat + "']").hide()
    }   else {
        $(subcategory).prop('disabled', true).val(0); 
    } 
});
```

Also, disable the subcategory and add `data-target="category-name"`

```
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" disabled="true">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="beanie" data-target="headwear">beanie</option>
    <option value="cap" data-target="headwear">cap</option>
    <option value="shirts" data-target="clothing">Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you @brian..i think i will use javascript instead to have the category and subcategory disabled or enable. i run the example on  jsFiddle an am still able to select the same options on the subcategory-i wanted specif options related to my selection in category to only be displayed and not all of them.i hope you understand what am trying to say..

Comment: I updated my answer and fiddle link to also include the limiting of subcategories - enjoy

Comment: ps, you still need to disable the usage of sub-category until a category is selected.. otherwise there wont be a sub category to display

Comment: Thank you @Brian..exactly what i was after :)

Comment: Happy to have helped :)